# Access and modify db from within jar

Tags: java, sql, jar

If I package a application I wrote in java that writes and reads from an sql db into a jar and distribute, will the program be able to write to the db, close, be run again later, and still be able to read the data it wrote in the last session?

Comment: If you wrote it to do that and the database is configured for the right access... sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not?

Although the idea of code executing from a JAR file modifying that JAR file makes me a little queasy. I personally would store the database outside the JAR file.

Comment: Well I'm trying to create an incredibly portable program that retains all the info within one file. I have heard of programs accessing pictures that are stored within the data/assets area of the jar.